# SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation

Tags: php, sql, pdo, cardinality

I am runnig below code:

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Order (id, catalogue, Shopid, address) VALUES (:userid, :cartcatl, :shopid, :cartaddrid)');
$stmt->execute(array(':userid' => $id, ':cartcatl' => $catl, ':shopid' => $shopid, ':cartaddrid' => $addr));
```

On executing getting below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) in
```

Comment: what about copy/pasting here the full error message ? it's truncated after *in*...

Comment: Rather, what about just pasting the error message in the address bar

Comment: @Pierre after 'in' there is server path mentioning the line number.

Comment: @YourCommonSense tried doing so, but found only for select queries, not for insert query

Comment: and to which query this path points out?